# How do I display a thumbnail that has been generated after translation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After translating a file to SVF I can see that there is thumbnails that have been generated.
How do I use the URN to display these thumbnails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Thumbnail endpoint to download the picture, but it requires the Token. So you can, for instance, download it on your server-side (with the token) and redirect the stream to the client-side (from your server).

Here is the thumbnail endpoint: '/modelderivative/' + MD_PROJECT_VERSION + '/designdata/' + urn + '/thumbnail?width=XXX&height=XXX';

And an example (NodeJS)

```
getThumbnail: function (thumbnailUrn, onsuccess){
    request({
        url: '/modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + thumbnailUrn + '/thumbnail?width=100&height=100';,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        encoding: null
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        onsuccess(new Buffer(body, 'base64'));
    });
},
```

And an NodeJS router:

```
router.get('/thumbnail', function (req, res) {
   getThumbnail(req.query.urn, function (thumb) {
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'image/png');
        res.end(thumb);
    });
});
```

Finally at your HTML you can just use:

```
<img src="/thumbnail?urn=XxXxXxXxX">
```

Comment: Thanks Augusto! I will try that :)

Comment: @e-Jah, did it help?

Comment: I will try this week-end or Monday top :) thanks for checking in!

Comment: it works but I had to use the object URN, not the thumbnail URN. Is there a way to use the thumbnail URNs returned by a "translation"?

Comment: yes, and I should update my answer, try the URL described at https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow!

Comment: ok, this is working. thanks! I will mark the answer as accepted, but it might be good to add this solution as well to your answer :)