# How get a thumbnail in node.js axios from Autodesk Forge

Tags: node.js, reactjs, autodesk-forge

How do I get and parse translated PNG Thumbnail?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364497/how-do-i-display-a-thumbnail-that-has-been-generated-after-translation) and it is not working.

**Backend**:

```
get_thumbnail = (access_token,urn) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      Axios({
        method: "GET",
        url:
          "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/" +
          encodeURIComponent(urn) +
          "/thumbnail",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        }
      })
        .then( (response)=> {
          if(response.status == 200 ){
            resolve(Buffer.from(response.data).toString('base64'))
          }
        })
  })
};
```

output string has 18KB size! but itstartet with **77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAA** and not with standart PNG **iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...** and not displaying in frontend (react)

**frontend** :

```
<img width="150" height="150"src={`data:image/png;base64,${thumbnail}`}/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the response payload was somehow not taken as `UINT8Array` properly so try to construct the array like this:

```
new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'))
```

See more [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-viewer-data-serverlessly-thumbnails-screesnshots-and-serverless-upload)

Comment: found it, Thanks for Link! it was because of axios config. ```responseType: 'arraybuffer'``` it should be :  ```Axios({
        method: "GET",
        url:"thumbnail url",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })```